# Count query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the following to go from X to Y:

**tblStationary** ---> X

```
Name    Stationary
-------------------
Peter   Crayon
Peter   Pencil
Peter   Crayon
Peter   Crayon
Peter   Crayon
Peter   Pencil
John    Crayon
John    Crayon
```

to this query:     ----> Y

```
Stationary Amount
-----------------
Crayon     2
Pencil     1
```

Crayon and Pencil must only be counted once per person. ie: When Peter has 2 pencils it must be counted as 1. So forth

I tried the following and it does not help:

```
SELECT 
    Stationary, COUNT(Name) AS Number
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblStationary) AS t
GROUP BY 
    Stationary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your RDBMS supports `SELECT DISTINCT`, but if it does, you can use it like that:

```
SELECT Stationary, COUNT(Name) AS Number
FROM (select DISTINCT * FROM dbo.tblStationary) as t
GROUP BY Stationary
```

So I just added a `DISTINCT` in the inner query.

Comment: This query will return count 1 for which name has only one stationary whereas in your question you have clearly mentioned that 'Peter has 2 pencils it must be counted as 1' and I am sure it won't satisfy this condition

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` will output every combination of (person,stationary) only once. So it is counted once.

Answer (score 1):

If so then we can simply done it as following

```
SELECT Stationary, COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) AS Number
FROM tblStationary
GROUP BY Stationary
```

Comment: This is the better answer.